React native Nested Scrollview/Section List with Sticky elements in both Parent and Child View/List not sticking
I am trying to create a page where there are sticky elements in both parent and child views. I tried with ScrollViews and SectionList with StickyHeaders to achieve but none worked. Here is what i am looking for:

In outer ScrollView there will be tabs which will stick to top on scroll
In Inner ScrollView one item has a sticky header which should stick to top on scroll rest should scroll normally.

When i tried to use nested scrollviews/section lists the inner header/element is not getting stick to top. Only outer tabs are getting sticky.
Create a snack here for demo: https://snack.expo.dev/@praveens96/reanimated-nested-sticky-views
In the above snack, the tabs would stick to the top on scroll but labels should also stick to top on scroll.
Any help would be appreciated.

Note: StickyHeaderIndices, enableStickyHeader etc didn't work when used on inner Scrollview. When using them on outer scrollview behaviour is not as expected, scrolling is not working as required.

replaced scrollviews with section lists

Hi, I am experiencing the same issue and have tried to use section lists but without any luck, could you post your solution?
